# How to sort a List of Lists in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I have a List of lists i.e. `IList<IList<Result>>`, I need to sort by property `DisplayOrder`.

```
IList<IList<Result>> results = new List<IList<Result>>();

results = validationResults.OrderBy(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.DisplayOrder)).ToList();
```

**`validationResults` value:**

```
[
    [
        {
            "fieldName": "AccountName",
            "displayOrder": 5
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "fieldName": "AccountNumber",
            "displayOrder": 6
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "fieldName": "BankAddress",
            "displayOrder": 4
        }
    ]
]
```

**Expected value:**

```
[
    [
        {
            "fieldName": "BankAddress",
            "displayOrder": 4
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "fieldName": "AccountName",
            "displayOrder": 5
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "fieldName": "AccountNumber",
            "displayOrder": 6
        }
    ] 
]
```

I have tried but it is giving the below exception.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compare two elements in
> the array.  ---> System.ArgumentException: At least one object must
> implement IComparable.    at
> System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)    at
> System.Collections.Generic.ObjectComparer`1.Compare(T x, T y)    at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.CompareAnyKeys(Int32 index1, Int32
> index2)    at
> System.Collections.Generic.ComparisonComparer`1.Compare(T x, T y)    at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.InsertionSort(T[]
> keys, Int32 lo, Int32 hi, Comparison`1 comparer)    at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.IntroSort(T[] keys, Int32
> lo, Int32 hi, Int32 depthLimit, Comparison`1 comparer)    at System.Collections.Generic.GenericArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys,
> Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Collections.Generic.GenericArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys,
> Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)    at System.Array.Sort[T](T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1
> comparer)    at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.QuickSort(Int32[] keys, Int32 lo, Int32 hi)    at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
> at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.ToList()    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
> Api.Controllers.ValidationController.ValidateFields(ValidateFieldsRequest
> validateFieldsRequest) in
> J:\Api\ValidationApi\ValidationApi\Controllers\ValidationController.cs:line
> 191

**Note**: I am using .net core 3.1

**Edit**: I have added the equivalent JSON just for the readability purpose so that others can easily understand and debug the issue. Yes, `Result` class has a property `DisplayOrder`. I want to sort the outer list . and `IList<Result>` has always only one item.

Comment: Why not flatten the list of lists into a single list, then sort that?

Comment: How does `Result` related to expected value?

Comment: I don’t want to change the original structure of list. And does it affect the performance also? @Neil

Comment: Once sorted, you can then project back to the original list of lists.

Comment: Result class has DisplayOrder property, I think it should be clear by seeing the code only . @PavelAnikhouski

Comment: @Neil but how??

Comment: Do please give us the `Result` class definition and the code to load the JSON.

Comment: @viveknuna first post a valid C# example, don't force people to convert that JSON string into C# by hand. Explain what you actually want to - looks like you want to reorder the outer list based on the `displayOrder` of the first item of the inner lists. That shouldn't be too hard - unless you want to sort the inner list too? What if there are 2 items or none?

Comment: If you want to order by the first inner item, `validationResults.OrderBy(x => x.First().DisplayOrder).ToList()` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatten the list, sort and then project back to the list of lists:

```
results = validationResults
    .SelectMany(x=>x) // Flatten
    .OrderBy(x=>x.DisplayOrder) // sort
    .Select(x=>new List<Result>{x}); // Project to list of lists
```

(I haven't checked this compiles, but hopefully you get the idea).

Comment: Its working for me, thank you Neil. Downvoters, could you please explain why have you downvoted his answer?

Comment: Because that's not what you asked? Because you showed sorting by the first item only? This isn't a bad answer *assuming the structure doesn't matter*. You haven't specified that though, the question is unclear

Comment: @viveknuna and answering bad questions is frowned upon because it harms everyone - people that may have a similar question in the future will be confused by the unclear question, not understand how the answer relates, perhaps try to use an inappropriate solution simply because it sounded similar to their problem. When you ask a question you have to make sure the question is a good one.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos its very clear from the question that I want to sort on the property DisplayOrder. If you don't want to understand at all and want to find out mistakes in others, it's completely fine. For me, I have given credit to him because it answers my questions and its basic courtesy to appreciate others efforts

Comment: @viveknuna you've made a string of unclear questions over the past weeks. I haven't downvoted any of them up to now but frankly - others are getting downvoted due to the inaccurate questions. Clean up your question, so I can upvote this answer. And *please* make sure your questions are clear

Comment: If it was not clear to everyone then I think @neil would not have been able to answer the question correctly.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am happy to take your input and suggestions. but could you please let me know what is missing and unclear in my question. and please provide me reasons for the string of inaccurate questions and you can happily downvote.

Comment: @viveknuna read the comments under the question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have updated my question. I reread the question again and clarified everything. Thank you for your suggestions. Did it make you happy to downvote my questions? please provide the reason also so that it can really help others if that is your intention

Answer (score 0):

You can either wrap the list with you own list or write IComparable as an extension method.